# Google Cloud Dataflow Error | apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pipeline, apache-beam, dataflow

I have developed a wordcount pipeline using apache beam and I am able to run the python code locally on my machine. But while trying to do that on Dataflow getting this error.

> apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing
> https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/mw-da-training/locations/%3Dus-central/jobs?alt=json:
> response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type':
> 'application/json;  charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri, 27 May 2022 11:56:56
> GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection':
> '0',  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options':
> 'nosniff', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443";
> ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443";
> ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000;
> v="46,43"', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '403',
> 'content-length': '158', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
> "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "Permission denied on 'locations/=us-central' (or it may not exist).",
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"   } }

Comment: do you receive this error when trying to submit the job?

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to authenticate your pipeline with Google Cloud. There's a few ways of doing this:

##### Using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

This is an environment variable that Google applications use to authenticate with Google Cloud. You would:

1. [Download a service account key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#get-key) and store as a file (e.g. `my_credential.json`).
2. Point the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable to this file (i.e. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/my_credentials.json`).
3. You're good to go. Run your pipeline!

#### Using `gcloud` to log in

1. Log in to your own user account using `gcloud auth application-default login`. This will set up the application default login for your session.
2. You're good to go. Run your pipeline!